# Moving Files with certain File Name

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script which detects a folder called `Post` within the subfolders of `W:\SUS Test2` and moves CSV file which has "EMMain" in the filename. But the problem I have is the CSV files doesn't copy to the destination folder `W:\SUS Test3` it copies it to `W:\SUS Test2` folder.

```
$path = "W:\SUS Test2\"
$destination = "W:\SUS Test3\"
$fsw = New-Object  System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $path -Property @{
  IncludeSubdirectories = $true
  NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'DirectoryName
}

$createdLTC = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw -EventName Created -Action {
  $item =  Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath

  if ($item.Name -like "Post") {
    Get-ChildItem $item -filter "*EMMain*" | Copy-Item -dest $destination
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the `$destination` variable in a portion of code that it is not available in.  The script block in your `Register-OjbectEvent` will not have access to this variable.  Try declaring $destination in the script block directly.

```
$createdLTC = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw -EventName Created -Action {
    $destination = "W:\SUS Test3\"
    $item =  Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath
    If ($item.Name -like "Post") {
          Get-ChildItem $item -filter "*EMMain*" | Copy-Item -dest $destination 
    } 
  }
```